# Statistical test to investigate multiple data sets whether they are independent

Tags: clustering, statistical-significance

I had an 18 variable original data. I did principal component analysis and converted it to 6 PCs explaining 75% of the variance of original data. The I clustered the 6 PCs. For that, I first used average linkage to calculate the mean value of the PC scores with certain number of clusters (I tried 3,4,5,6). Then I used the mean values and number of clusters as seeds for K means clustering and got 4 clusters.

Now I have got a problem. What test should i use to know how significant is the clustering procedure? one way is of course calculating the means and standard deviation of the original 18 variables with each of the four clusters. But I am looking for a statistical test which can prove that the new 4 data sets are independent and the clustering is significant.